# Removing account from AccountManager doesn't send user to AccountAuthenticatorActivity

Tags: android, authentication, android-service, accountmanager, android-authenticator

I have an app that registers users using AccountManager and custom AccountAuthenticator.

I need to implement the `Log Out` functionality.

When user clicks the `Log Out` button, their account gets removed successfully, but the activity stays the same, the user doesn't get redirected to the `AccountAuthenticatorActivity`, although if I close the app and open it again, it will show the authentication screen (i.e. the account actually was removed).

#### My question:

Do I have to perform the redirection myself (using `finish(); startActivity(...);`) or the Authenticator and AccountManager should handle it for me (because I thought that if it is declared as a service, it should)?

---

Maybe I have to implement some sort of account removal listener?

Anyway, here's how I delete the account in `MainActivity`:

```
    private void performLogout() {
        Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType(AccountGeneral.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
        if (accounts.length != 0) {    
            accountManager.clearPassword(accounts[0]);
            accountManager.invalidateAuthToken(AccountGeneral.ACCOUNT_TYPE,
                    accountManager.getAuthToken(accounts[0], AccountGeneral.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE_FULL_ACCESS, null, true,
                            accountManagerFuture -> {
                                try {
                                    Log.d("invalidateAuthToken", accountManagerFuture.getResult().toString());
                                } catch (android.accounts.OperationCanceledException | AuthenticatorException | IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }, null).toString());

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) { // use deprecated method
              accountManager.removeAccount(accounts[0], accountManagerFuture -> {
                  try {
                      if (accountManagerFuture.getResult()) {
                          Log.d("Deprecated ACCOUNT REMOVAL", "ACCOUNT  REMOVED");

                      }
                  } catch (android.accounts.OperationCanceledException | IOException | AuthenticatorException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }
              }, null);
          } else {
              accountManager.removeAccount(accounts[0], this, accountManagerFuture -> {
                  try {
                      if (accountManagerFuture.getResult() != null) {
                          Log.d("ACCOUNT REMOVAL", "ACCOUNT REMOVED");
                      }
                  } catch (android.accounts.OperationCanceledException | AuthenticatorException | IOException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }
              }, null);
          }
        }
    }
```

BTW, when I click `Log Out`, I can see in the logs the following line:

> D/invalidateAuthToken: Bundle[{intent=Intent { cat=[2]
>   cmp=discounty.com/.activities.LoginActivity (has extras) }}]

so it seems that my `LoginActivity` (AccountAuthenticatorActivity) actually wants to appear but something prevents it from doing so.

In my custom `AccountAuthenticator` I have this method implemented (and a couple of others responsible for account and token creation):

```
@Override
public Bundle getAccountRemovalAllowed(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account) throws NetworkErrorException {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    boolean allowed = true;
    bundle.putBoolean(AccountManager.KEY_BOOLEAN_RESULT, allowed);
    return bundle;
}
```

and in my manifest I have the service declared the following way:

```
<service
    android:name=".authenticator.DiscountyAuthenticationService"
    android:process=":auth">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
        android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
</service>
```

---

So, do I have to redirect the users manually or I need to improve something in my code to make AccountManager handle the redirection for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AccountManager doesn't start another account setup when you remove an account. If you want that behavior, you need to implement it yourself.

However, I would not advise to implement it that way. If you click on "log out" you don't expect to be redirected directly to the login screen again.

Instead I would show a success message like "Logged out successfully" with two buttons, one that says something like "Close" and closes the app and one that says something like "login again" which takes the user to the login screen again. That's more user friendly, IMHO.

Anyway, to answer your question: If you want to go to the login screen automatically I see the following options:

1. Just launch the Account setup (using [AccountManager.addAccount(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#addAccount%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.Activity,%20android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback%3Candroid.os.Bundle%3E,%20android.os.Handler%29)) when the user hits "logout" (optionally remove the account with [AccountManager.removeAccountExplicitly(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#removeAccountExplicitly%28android.accounts.Account%29)). Removing an account (of your own app) is unlikely to fail (especially if you allows return `true` in `getAccountRemovalAllowed(...)`), so in most cases it should be safe to assume the removal succeeded. Your Authenticator has to deal with the case that the account already exists anyway, since the user can launch the account setup at any time.
2. Wait for `accountManagerFuture.getResult()` and start the account setup just like in #1 only if it returns success.
3. Register an [OnAccountsUpdateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/OnAccountsUpdateListener.html) using [addOnAccountsUpdatedListener(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#addOnAccountsUpdatedListener%28android.accounts.OnAccountsUpdateListener,%20android.os.Handler,%20boolean%29) in your Activity that checks if the account exists or not. Note that there are three triggers that cause this listener to be called:

   a. An account has been created, including accounts of other apps

   b. An account has been removed, including accounts of other apps

   c. The password of an account has been updated, also including accounts of other apps (IMHO this event should be private to the authenticator and should definitely not broadcasted).

   However, the callback won't receive any information what the trigger was. So you need to find out yourself if your account was removed.

Also note, that your code seems to call `accountManagerFuture.getResult()` in the main thread, which is not a good idea since it may block. The documentation of [AccountManager.removeAccount(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#removeAccount%28android.accounts.Account,%20android.app.Activity,%20android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback%3Candroid.os.Bundle%3E,%20android.os.Handler%29) explicitly says this is not allowed. Even if you're calling it in the `AccountManagerCallback` callback and you probably can assume that it's safe to call it I wouldn't rely on it and make sure it's executed in a background thread. If you don't let the user confirm the removal, you probably should call [AccountManager.removeAccountExplicitly(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#removeAccountExplicitly%28android.accounts.Account%29) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the elucidating answer.
Do you happen to know what the best equivalent of `removeAccountExcplicitly` is if I need to use API level 21?

Comment: We use `AccountManager.removeAccount(account, null, null);`. If `getAccountRemovalAllowed` returns `true`, that's basically the same operation. On API levels below 22 there doesn't seem to be a way to bypass the call to `getAccountRemovalAllowed`, which is basically what `removeAccountExplicitly` does.